# Make footer stick to bottom and not overlapp container

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to make this footer div stick to the bottom of my page, as well as not overlapping the container DIV.

https://jsfiddle.net/55frzot1/

I have unsuccessfully been trying to add a push class, with the same height as the footer:

```
.push {
    min-height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30487509/483779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `footer{ bottom:0px; position:fixed;}`

Answer (score 0):

remove `position: absolute` from your container, you dont need it.
give footer `position: fixed`, container needs `margin-bottom: 150px;`and you're done

https://jsfiddle.net/55frzot1/2/

Answer (score 0):

I though I'd take a shot at it and come up with my own solution which is just a tiny bit of css and html

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.body {
  min-height: calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.footer {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body">test as body</div>
  <div class="footer">test as footer</div>
</body>
```

this works by setting the height of the footer and then using css calc to work out the minimum height the page can be with the footer still at the bottom, hope this helps come people :)